# Oracle Join with NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, null, left-join, self-join

I'm trying to get the latest revision for each submission number and I found a way to do it by using `LEFT JOIN` - I lost the link to the SO question. But now my problem is that when the submission number is `NULL` it seems to return more than what I expect.

#### Revision Table

```
---------------------------------------------------
id     submission_number     revision_created
---------------------------------------------------
1000   B00018                11/24/2016 10:45:34 AM
1001   B00018                11/25/2016 09:01:22 AM
1002   B00018                11/25/2016 03:35:01 PM
1003   NULL                  11/26/2016 09:09:11 AM
1004   NULL                  11/30/2016 03:45:22 PM
2000   B00032                10/01/2016 02:00:45 PM
3000   B00041                11/03/2016 11:03:10 AM
3001   B00041                11/05/2016 09:51:09 AM
```

In those examples I want to get

#### Desired Output

```
---------------------------------------------------
id     submission_number     revision_created
---------------------------------------------------
1002   B00018                11/25/2016 03:35:01 PM
1004   NULL                  11/30/2016 03:45:22 PM
2000   B00032                10/01/2016 02:00:45 PM
3001   B00041                11/05/2016 09:51:09 AM
```

Basically I only want to get 1 revision for each submission numbers which should be the latest revision. This is the query I found in StackOverflow which I used:

#### Query

```
SELECT r.id, r.revision_created, r.submission_number
FROM revision r
  LEFT JOIN revision jt
    ON (
      r.submission_number = jt.submission_number
      AND r.revision_created < jt.revision_created
    )
WHERE jt.revision_created IS NULL
```

The query above works if the submission number has a value. If it is `NULL`, I get a lot of rows when I only expect 1.

#### My Attempted Solution

I tried to change the `JOIN ON` clause to be

```
ON (
  r.submission_number = jt.submission_number OR (r.submission_number IS NULL AND jt.submission_number IS NULL)
  AND r.revision_created < jt.revision_created
)
```

But my change actually removed the revision where the submission number is `NULL`.

#### Limitations

Also before I forget I'm supposed to do this inside a software where I am limited in terms of Oracle functions I can use. So things like `MAX`, `MIN`, `REPLACE`, etc. isn't supported.

Comment: I understand `REPLACE` is not supported, but the *aggregate* (not the *analytic*) versions of `MAX()` and `MIN()` aren't supported either? That sounds like software that shouldn't be used at all with a SQL-based database. And - it doesn't support aggregate functions but it supports joins?

Comment: If software doesn't support max you can create a view on database side which produce only top revision for each submission and the use view in query. Or software also not support views?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that only the analytic versions (not the AGGREGATE versions) of `MIN` and `MAX` are out of bounds, you could do something like this:

**Preparation** (so I don't need to mess with `to_date()` and `to_char()`):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM';

Session altered.
```

Then:

```
with
     revision ( id, submission_number, revision_created ) as (
       select 1000, 'B00018', '11/24/2016 10:45:34 AM' from dual union all
       select 1001, 'B00018', '11/25/2016 09:01:22 AM' from dual union all
       select 1002, 'B00018', '11/25/2016 03:35:01 PM' from dual union all
       select 1003, NULL    , '11/26/2016 09:09:11 AM' from dual union all
       select 1004, NULL    , '11/30/2016 03:45:22 PM' from dual union all
       select 2000, 'B00032', '10/01/2016 02:00:45 PM' from dual union all
       select 3000, 'B00041', '11/03/2016 11:03:10 AM' from dual union all
       select 3001, 'B00041', '11/05/2016 09:51:09 AM' from dual
     )
-- end of test data; solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select r.id, r.submission_number, r.revision_created
from   revision r inner join
       ( select submission_number, max(revision_created) as max_created
         from   revision
         group by submission_number
       ) g
       on  ( r.submission_number = g.submission_number
                  or r.submission_number is null and g.submission_number is null
           )
           and r.revision_created  = g.max_created
;

   ID SUBMISSION_NUMBER REVISION_CREATED
----- ----------------- ----------------------
 1001 B00018            11/25/2016 09:01:22 AM
 1004                   11/30/2016 03:45:22 PM
 2000 B00032            10/01/2016 02:00:45 PM
 3001 B00041            11/05/2016 09:51:09 AM

4 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a in subquery based  on group by for min revision_created

```
  SELECT r.id, r.revision_created, r.submission_number
  from revision r 
  where  (r.submission_number, r.revision_created) in ( 

      select submission_number, min(revision_created) 
      from revision
      group by submission_number
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the `NULL` join condition into your original attempt, like this:

```
SELECT r.id, r.revision_created, r.submission_number
FROM revision r
  LEFT JOIN revision jt
    ON (
      ( r.submission_number = jt.submission_number 
        OR ( r.submission_Number is null and jt.submission_number is null ) )
      AND r.revision_created < jt.revision_created
    )
WHERE jt.revision_created IS NULL;
```

That's definitely not the best way to do it in Oracle, but I think it follows the limitations you've given.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that only requires a single scan of the table...

```
with
     revision ( id, submission_number, revision_created ) as (
       select 1000, 'B00018', '11/24/2016 10:45:34 AM' from dual union all
       select 1001, 'B00018', '11/25/2016 09:01:22 AM' from dual union all
       select 1002, 'B00018', '11/25/2016 03:35:01 PM' from dual union all
       select 1003, NULL    , '11/26/2016 09:09:11 AM' from dual union all
       select 1004, NULL    , '11/30/2016 03:45:22 PM' from dual union all
       select 2000, 'B00032', '10/01/2016 02:00:45 PM' from dual union all
       select 3000, 'B00041', '11/03/2016 11:03:10 AM' from dual union all
       select 3001, 'B00041', '11/05/2016 09:51:09 AM' from dual
     )
select id, submission_number, revision_created 
from (
       select id, submission_number, revision_created 
        ,last_value( revision_created ) 
            over ( partition by submission_number order by revision_created
            rows  between unbounded preceding and unbounded following ) lv
       from revision
      )
where revision_created = lv
```